# django: Switch the inherited model base class to different child

Tags: django, django-models

The base class model and inherited models are as follow:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
   ...
class Student(Profile):
   ...
class Teacher(Profile):
   ...
```

I have object of Student class(the data for which are stored in two tables in db - Profile table and a Student table which has a pointer to Profile table). I need to assign that Profile table row to a Teacher object and delete the Student object, i.e. without losing the content of Profile table data and also retaining the same id for that row. How it should be done?

Thank you,

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Programmaticly or just a one-of task? If one-of, I would suggest you do it manually in the database. Otherwise, can't you create a new teacher object where you specify Profile_id = what you want. And then delete the Student?

Comment: It has to be done programmaticly, the other option(i.e profile_id = ) I was trying but was not able to get it correct, actually in case of inherited models the table field name was like profile_ptr_id, I was using that but it didn't worked out..

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, Django creates a field on the Student and Teacher models called profile_ptr_id. So you'll probably have to manipulate that. Because of how Django's concrete inheritance works, each Student and Teacher object's primary key is actually this profile_ptr_id field. Thus, I am not sure having both a Student and Teacher object with the same profile_ptr_ids is allowed.

One way you can try to get around this is the following:

- Create a new Profile object
- Set the Student object's profile_ptr_id to the id of the new Profile object
- Set the Teacher object's profile_ptr_id to the id of the old Profile object that the Student object was previously pointing to.
- Delete the Student object

I've never tried this, so I really can't say if it will work or not...

Comment: Actually I had already some data which are stored in reference to earlier profile ID(when it was used for student), now if that student is promoted to teacher profile I need to retain those data too, and those data have reference to profile ID(which will be lost if deleted)..

Comment: Right. The list of steps I wrote moves the old profile to the teacher, retaining all it's information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a student that you want to turn into a teacher with some or all fields, and you can afford to type out the fields, you can just do:

```
teacher = Teacher(id=student.id, user=student.user, 
                  name=student.name, email=student.email, ...)
student.delete()
teacher.save()
```

It's important to set the ID and delete the old object before saving the new one with the same ID.